# How to get a site screenshot quickly using PHP?

Tags: php, screenshot

I want to create a web directory site, and I need to get these site screenshots. How to get a site screenshot quickly using PHP?
I tried IECAPT,webscreencapture, khtml2png, but they are all slowly. And they all get screenshot one url by one url.
Is IECAPT depends on a ie browser? if it is, why it can not open many ie tags so that work at the same time?
Is there anyone can recommend me a PHP screenshots software using online? according to my above requirements? Thank you.

Comment: To let you know, PHP is a hypertext preprocessor, not renderer.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements are unrealistic. Your best bet is to integrate with WebKit through something like [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) that doesn't run an actual browser, but just the WebKit rendering engine. You shouldn't have any concurrency issues, but it it isn't going to be fantastic.

Comment: Yes, you can't use PHP (or any other server language) for capturing a web site because they can work with HTML but not *render* it. CutyCapt seems a nice utility for accomplish that.

Comment: Hi, coreyward, do you think some thumbnail service site, like pageglimpse.com What is the technology they use? I do not think they will installe many browsers on their web servers.

Comment: And I have tried CutyCapt, I copied 3 CutyCapt.exe and renamed them.

Comment: <?php
   set_time_limit(0);
   $url1 = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
   $out1 = '1.jpg';
   $path1 = 'CutyCapt1.exe';
   $cmd1 = "$path1 -u=$url1 -o=$out1";
   //exec($cmd);
   system($cmd2);
   $url2 = 'http://www.google.com';
   $out2 = '2.jpg';
   $path2 = 'CutyCapt2.exe';
   $height2 = '1200 ';
   $cmd2 = "$path2 -u=$url2 -o=$out2";
   //exec($cmd);
   system($cmd2);
   $url3 = 'http://www.google.co.jp';
   $out3 = '2.jpg';
   $path3 = 'CutyCapt3.exe';
   $height3 = '1200 ';
   $cmd2 = "$path3 -u=$url3 -o=$out3";
   //exec($cmd);
   system($cmd3);
?>

Comment: I use the php code like that, but it also catch the screenshot one by one , not run the 3 processes at one time.

Answer (score 2):

These external services are developing fast. Take a look at:
http://immediatenet.com/thumbnail_api.html
it renders thumbnails extremely fast and caches them like the other similar services.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use an external service. There used to be Alexa Site Thumbnail but it has been discontinued, so you must look for alternatives. For example http://www.pageglimpse.com/ seems to be one.

Comment: Hi, coreyward, do you think some thumbnail service site, like http://www.pageglimpse.com/ What is the technology they use? I do not think they will installe many browsers on their web servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried CutyCapt, I copied 3 CutyCapt.exe and renamed them. But it also catch the screenshot one by one , not run the 3 processes at one time.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$url1 = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
$out1 = '1.jpg';
$path1 = 'CutyCapt1.exe';
$cmd1 = "$path1 -u=$url1 -o=$out1";
//exec($cmd); 
system($cmd2); 
$url2 = 'http://www.google.com';
 $out2 = '2.jpg';
 $path2 = 'CutyCapt2.exe'; 
$height2 = '1200 ';
 $cmd2 = "$path2 -u=$url2 -o=$out2"; 
//exec($cmd); 
system($cmd2); 
$url3 = 'http://www.google.co.jp'; 
$out3 = '2.jpg';
 $path3 = 'CutyCapt3.exe';
 $height3 = '1200 '; 
$cmd2 = "$path3 -u=$url3 -o=$out3"; 
//exec($cmd); 
system($cmd3);`
?>
```

I do not think many thumbnail service site, like pageglimpse.com, they install many browsers on their web servers. What is the technology they use?